Ошибка OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: Telegram bot
Есть телеграм бот написанный на библиотеке aiogram.
Есть Сервер Linux Ubuntu 22.04.
Есть Установленный Docker на этом сервере.
Есть установленный локальный сервер Telegram.
Когда я запускаю бота из Pycharm на Windows или запускаю бота через собранный
Docker образ,
то при попытке отправить файл боту я получаю следующую ошибку:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 
'/home/purch_dep/telegram_bot_local_server/7161680398:<somebottoken>/documents/file_8.xlsx'
Traceback (most recent call last):

Но если я запускаю бота на самом сервер Linux (без Docker-a, просто командой python Bot.py) то проблем нет никаких, все работает абсолютно корректно.
Подозреваю, что проблема может быть в пути к файлу, но куда именно копать не пойму.
Вот сам код кнопки загрузки в боте:
@router.message(FSMAdmin.brands_upload_file)
async def upload_brands_to_db_by_excel(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
  print(os.getcwd())
  if message.content_type != 'document':
      await state.set_state(FSMAdmin.brands_upload_file)
      await message.answer(f"<b>Я принимаю только файлы.</b>",
                         parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML, reply_markup=markup_back)
  else:
    file_name = message.document.file_name
    file_extension = '.' + message.document.file_name.split('.')[-1]
    if file_extension != '.xlsx':
        await message.answer(f"<b>Я ПРИНИМАЮ ТОЛЬКО ФАЙЛЫ В ФОРМАТЕ .xlsx</b>",
                             parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML, reply_markup=markup_back)
    else:
        file_id = message.document.file_id
        file = await bot.get_file(file_id)
        file_path = file.file_path
        print(f"File PATH {file_path}")
        server_file_name = file_path.split('/')[-1]
        server_file_path = file_path.split('/')[:-1]
        server_file_path = '/'.join(server_file_path)
        print(f"CURR WORK DIR {os.getcwd()}")

        await bot.download_file(file_path=f"{file_path}", destination=f"tmp/{file_name}")
        await message.answer('<b>БОТ НАЧАЛ ОБРАБАТЫВАТЬ ДАННЫЕ, ОЖИДАЙТЕ...</b>', parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
        is_added = add_brands_to_db(get_data_from_downloaded_file(file_name, is_truck_brands=True))
        if is_added:
            clear_folder([file_name], 'tmp/')
            clear_folder([server_file_name], f"{server_file_path}")
            await message.answer(f"<b>ДАННЫЕ  УСПЕШНО ДОБАВЛЕНЫ В БД.</b>\n\n{emoji.emojize(':file_folder:')}"
                                 f" Добавлен документ: <b><i>{file_name}</i></b>", parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML,
                                 reply_markup=markup_add_constants)
            await state.clear()
        else:
            await message.answer(f"<b>ДАННЫЕ НЕ ДОБАВЛЕНЫ, ОБРАТИТЕСЬ К АДМИНИСТРАТОРУ</b>",
                                 parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML, reply_markup=markup_back)

вот полный Traceback:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/home/purch_dep/telegram_bot_local_server/7161680398:A<somebottoken>/documents/file_8.xlsx'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 309, in _process_update
    response = await self.feed_update(bot, update, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 158, in feed_update
    response = await self.update.wrap_outer_middleware(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares\error.py", line 25, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares\user_context.py", line 56, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\fsm\middleware.py", line 42, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 276, in _listen_update
    return await self.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 146, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 141, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 174, in _propagate_event
    response = await router.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 146, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 141, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 166, in _propagate_event
    response = await observer.trigger(event, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\Bot.py", line 422, in upload_brands_to_db_by_excel
    await bot.download_file(file_path=f"{file_path}", destination=f"tmp/{file_name}")
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\bot.py", line 430, in download_file
    await self.__download_file(destination=destination, stream=stream)
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\bot.py", line 379, in __download_file
    async for chunk in stream:
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\bot.py", line 386, in __aiofiles_reader
    async with aiofiles.open(file, "rb") as f:
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiofiles\base.py", line 98, in __aenter__
    self._obj = await self._coro
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Purchasing_department\QWEP_daily_prices\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiofiles\threadpool\__init__.py", line 94, in _open
    f = yield from loop.run_in_executor(executor, cb)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/home/purch_dep/telegram_bot_local_server/7161680398:<somebottoken>/documents/file_8.xlsx'


Файловая система Docker изолирована от хост-системы — путь, который бот пытается использовать для загрузки файла, возможно, не существует внутри контейнера. Убедитесь, пожалуйста, что файлы и директории, с которыми работает бот, действительно доступны внутри контейнера.
Также приложите, пожалуйста, полный Traceback.

Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

7161680398 — это похоже на id чата, вам необходимо проверить пути и файлы, и доступ к ним. Чтобы вы смогли получить ответ на ru.SO создайте пример минимальный. Также пожалуйста удалите ответ, добавив ошибку в сам вопрос. ===> как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
